Exact backpropagation formula for gradients vs online source
I visited this website that showed a simple backpropagation technique being applied on a built-from-scratch ANN. The code is in python and looks like this:
    # once you understand the chain rule it becomes super easy
    # to implement with a 'for' loop -- simply loop over the
    # layers in reverse order (ignoring the last two since we
    # already have taken them into account)
    for layer in np.arange(len(A) - 2, 0, -1):
        # the delta for the current layer is equal to the delta
        # of the *previous layer* dotted with the weight matrix
        # of the current layer, followed by multiplying the delta
        # by the derivative of the nonlinear activation function
        # for the activations of the current layer
        delta = D[-1].dot(self.W[layer].T)
        delta = delta * self.sigmoid_deriv(A[layer])
        D.append(delta)

and the second part:
    # since we looped over our layers in reverse order we need to
    # reverse the deltas
    D = D[::-1]
    # WEIGHT UPDATE PHASE
    # loop over the layers
    for layer in np.arange(0, len(self.W)):
        # update our weights by taking the dot product of the layer
        # activations with their respective deltas, then multiplying
        # this value by some small learning rate and adding to our
        # weight matrix -- this is where the actual "learning" takes
        # place
        self.W[layer] += -self.alpha * A[layer].T.dot(D[layer])

Assuming  D[-1] in the first code example is equal to $2(predicted - actual)$ and there is only one output neuron.
This code seems to indicate that the gradient for  the second layer of weights would be:
$2(predicted - actual)\cdot(W^{(L-1)})^T \circ (a^{(L-1)}\circ(1-a^{(L-1)}))\cdot a^{(L-2)}$
since in the final dot product, both tensors have the same dimensions(assumption) then the result would be a single scalar gradient for ALL the weights. I would have thought that since in the original case for the first layer of weights, $ 2(predicted - actual)\cdot a^{(L-1)}$, gives a vector gradient for all individual gradients for each weight, the next layer down should do the same. This just does not make sense to me. Can someone explain why this is not the case? What happens if $a^{(L-1)}$ and $a^{(L-2)}$ have different dimensions(how do we  calculate the gradient then)?
link to the  tutorial:
https://pyimagesearch.com/2021/05/06/backpropagation-from-scratch-with-python/
